# Pandas rolling sum on string column

Tags: pandas, text, rolling-sum

I'm using Python3 with pandas version '0.19.2'.

I have a pandas df as follows:

```
chat_id    line
1          'Hi.'
1          'Hi, how are you?.'
1          'I'm well, thanks.'
2          'Is it going to rain?.'
2          'No, I don't think so.'
```

I want to group by 'chat_id', then do something like a rolling sum on 'line' to get the following:

```
chat_id    line                     conversation
1          'Hi.'                    'Hi.'
1          'Hi, how are you?.'      'Hi. Hi, how are you?.'
1          'I'm well, thanks.'      'Hi. Hi, how are you?. I'm well, thanks.'
2          'Is it going to rain?.'  'Is it going to rain?.'
2          'No, I don't think so.'  'Is it going to rain?. No, I don't think so.'
```

I believe df.groupby('chat_id')['line'].cumsum() would only work on a numeric column.

I have also tried df.groupby(by=['chat_id'], as_index=False)['line'].apply(list) to get a list of all the lines in the full conversation, but then I can't figure out how to unpack that list to create the 'rolling sum' style conversation column.

Comment: Interesting. `cumsum` works if you call it on a Series but raises an error when called on a groupby object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me works [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), if need separator add `space`:

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('chat_id')['line'].apply(lambda x: (x + ' ').cumsum().str.strip())
print (df)
   chat_id                   line                                          new
0        1                    Hi.                                          Hi.
1        1      Hi, how are you?.                        Hi. Hi, how are you?.
2        1      I'm well, thanks.      Hi. Hi, how are you?. I'm well, thanks.
3        2  Is it going to rain?.                        Is it going to rain?.
4        2  No, I don't think so.  Is it going to rain?. No, I don't think so.
```

---

```
df['line'] = df['line'].str.strip("'")
df['new'] = df.groupby('chat_id')['line'].apply(lambda x: "'" + (x + ' ').cumsum().str.strip() + "'")
print (df)
   chat_id                   line  \
0        1                    Hi.   
1        1      Hi, how are you?.   
2        1      I'm well, thanks.   
3        2  Is it going to rain?.   
4        2  No, I don't think so.   

                                             new  
0                                          'Hi.'  
1                        'Hi. Hi, how are you?.'  
2      'Hi. Hi, how are you?. I'm well, thanks.'  
3                        'Is it going to rain?.'  
4  'Is it going to rain?. No, I don't think so.'
```

Comment: For me that results in:   
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: What is your version of pandas? `print (pd.show_versions())`. Because I cannot simulate your error. I test duplicates in values, duplicates in index and all works perfectly in version `0.19.2`.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I had to reset_index() on the df and then it worked.

Comment: If I have a `NaN` values in between the conversation (for example at `index 1`), how can I exclude that from `cumsum`-ing it? Thanks!

Comment: @TotoLele - One idea `df['new'] = df.dropna(subset=['line']).groupby('chat_id')['line'].apply(lambda x: (x + ' ').cumsum().str.strip())`